# How to configure Websphere 6.1 to develop applications with Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, websphere-6.1, ibm-rad

I have developed a small application with Struts 2 using RAD, but when I deploy to the server, it throws this error in the browser:

```
Error 500: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized
```

and these errors on the console:

```
[20/11/14 16:39:59:534 GMT] 00000023 WebApp        E   [Servlet Error]-[Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized]: Unable to load configuration. - bean - wsjar:file:/C:/cperezi/proyectos%20java/DemoStruts2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/HolaMundoEAR.ear/HolaMundo.war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.16.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:501)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.init(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:142)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager._loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:438)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.loadFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:352)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterInstanceWrapper(WebAppFilterManager.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.getFilterChain(WebAppFilterManager.java:272)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:661)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:646)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:628)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.invokeFilters(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:145)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:467)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:111)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3129)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:238)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:811)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1433)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:93)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:465)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:394)
at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:274)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:152)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:213)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.fireCompletionActions(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:195)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:194)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:741)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:863)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1510)
```

I checked the link below, but the problem still persists, can anyone give me another opinion? Thanks and regards

http://blog.btmatthews.com/?p=30

Comment: You're just another victim of GXP plugin. Remove unused JARs from your webapp, and it will work

Comment: But the exception has changed, hasn't it? Then what about posting the new one?

Comment: Your problem isn't with websphere, at least not yet. You have some jars that your app doesn't need, remove them.